# Java - Neo4J Rest call to put labels to nodes

Tags: java, neo4j

I've been trying to place labels over newly created nodes using Neo4J restful api. The following is the CURL request I've tried.

```js
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:7474/db/data/");

String propertyUri_labels = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9/labels";

Response response = target
                .path(propertyUri_labels)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("application/xml", "true")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .put(Entity.entity("\"" + "Artist" + "\"", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
        
System.out.println( String.format( "PUT to [%s], status code [%d]",
                propertyUri_labels, response.getStatus() ) );
```

However, I have not been successful and got an status code [400]. Is there something wrong with my URL "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/9/labels" ?

Pls help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a POST instead of PUT.
Check the documentation => http://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-node-labels

Comment: I tried using it but is unsuccessful in adding a label to my node.Response response = target
                .path("http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/4/labels")
                .request()
                .post(Entity.text("Band"));      Is it wrong?

Comment: Can you try to add the content-type of the request to `application/json` ?